# How to apply metada in hasura using multiple metadata files

Tags: graphql, continuous-deployment, hasura

I have a repository with my basic metadata files for Hasura, also in my production Hasura I'm always adding new metadata configuration like roles but this information shouldn't be stored in the repository because is dynamically generated with an external application and is not always the same.

How could I manage the deploy of new metadata changes from my repository?

I was thinking to implement in my CI/CD flow to export the current production metadata and merge it with the metadata that I stored in the repository could be an option but I'm looking to another ideas.

Comment: Can you please take a look [here](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/hasura-cli/hasura_metadata.html) if it can help? I think you can use CLI to programmatically achieve that.

Comment: yes, I was thinking in use the cli to export my current production metadata, then ,merge it with my repository metadata file and and finally the apply it to production again, all of this using the CLI. I think this could be done but I'm not sure if is the best approach.

Comment: I think it's the only way right now because currently Hasura doesn't have another way to work with metadata programmatically except CLI. Maybe later, community will have another tool or so for that. Hope so.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this course ["Local Dev to Staging to getting Production-Ready with Hasura!"](https://hasura.io/blog/moving-from-local-development-staging-production-with-hasura/).

Also, I'm not sure changing metadata in your production environnement is a good practice. You should rethink your roles workflow...

Anyway. You could export your metadata from your server in your repository:

```
hasura metadata export --endpoint https://hasura.prod
```

And then, reload the metadata:

```
hasura metadata reload
```